# tar listing only files of an archive and not directories

Tags: tar

How do I list only the contents of a tar file that are actual files or links to files and not directories?

I ask this because I want to take the tar -tf of an archive then retrieve the files in it from another directory.

Answer (score 2):

One option (assuming you are on a *NIX system) is to parse and filter the output from a verbose listing

```
tar -tvf abc.tar | awk '!/^d/ {print $NF}'
```

Although this is fraught with all the perils of [parsing ls output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: This doesn't work ?
```bash
$ tar --list --file=archive.tar | head -n2
>> mp3s/6c4/M04/7D/26/
>> mp3s/6c4/M04/7D/26/audiomp3
$ tar --list --file=archive.tar | head -n2 | awk '!/^d/ {print $NF}'
>> mp3s/6c4/M04/7D/26/
>> mp3s/6c4/M04/7D/26/audiomp3
```

Comment: @leonardltk1: The answer mentions generating a verbose listing from tar. When using only long options, include the flag `--verbose`.